# Canvas code not working in Fiddle

Tags: jquery, canvas, jsfiddle

The `images` don't seem to show up here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3Qkc6/

Comment: Clicking on `Run` worked for me...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3Qkc6/2/ Yeah this works for me! Just click run!

Comment: I did...didn't seem to load anything.

Comment: I was using **Maxthon**, didn't know that it did not support Canvas. Worked fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fiddle related issue. You need to change the type of javaScript injection. Just change the second dropdown on left from `onDomready` to `No wrap - in <head>` to get your fiddle working.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qkc6/1/) should work.

---

Edit: As you don't call a function within your HTML file, this change is not even necessary (But still reasonable). Simply press the run button as already stated within the comments.